# How to fade in/out stationary elements on scroll in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

### Problem

I'm attempting to have some background images fade to black when the user scrolls. However, I'd like these images to remain in the center of the screen while they are fading out.

This requirement creates a problem as I can't use `window.scrollY` or `e.target.scrollTop` as neither the element or the window is moving during this fade.

This project has taken heavy inspiration from the intro to this [website](https://the-goonies.webflow.io/). Note how the scrolling still controls the fade meaning it's not just a timer animation, somehow the stationary content is conveying scrolling information to the opacity of the black overlay.

### Attempts

1. As I said before, my first attempts at using scrollY or scrollTop had both those values remain at zero
2. I then tried to have a dynamic margin-top which just matched the scroll speed. But then there still was no way to control the fading

### Failed Code

```js
<script lang="ts">
    const INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH = 1500;
    const FADE_SCROLL_LENGTH = 800;
    let y: number;
    function clamp(input: number, min: number, max: number) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(input, min), max);
    }
    const elementScrollY = (e) => {
        if (!e.target.scrollTop) {
            return;
        }
        y = e.target.scrollTop;
        console.log(e.target.scrollTop);
    };
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} />

<section
    class="wrapper scroll-lock"
    on:scroll|preventDefault={elementScrollY}
    style="margin-top: {y}px;"
>
    <div class="debug-stats">{y}</div>
    <div
        class="intro-darkener"
        style="opacity: {100 * clamp((y - INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH) / FADE_SCROLL_LENGTH, 0, 1)}%;"
    />
    <div
        class="intro-foreground"
        style="transform: scale3d(
            {clamp((0.7 * y) / INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH + 1, 1, 1.7)}, 
            {clamp((0.7 * y) / INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH + 1, 1, 1.7)}, 
            1);"
    />
    <div
        class="intro-background"
        style="transform: scale3d(
            {clamp((0.3 * y) / INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH + 1, 1, 1.3)}, 
            {clamp((0.3 * y) / INTRO_SCROLL_LENGTH + 1, 1, 1.3)}, 
            1);"
    />
</section>

<style lang="postcss">
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .debug-stats {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .intro-background {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url('background.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .intro-foreground {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 100%;
        height: 110vh;
        background-image: url('foreground.png');
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        will-change: transform;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .intro-darkener {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .scroll-lock {
        overflow-y: visible;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image on the website you linked isn't moving because it's in an element with

```
position:sticky;
top: 0px;
```

which itself is in a container with

```
height: 260vh;
```

The sticky content will leave the viewport with the end of this container.

Changing values can be calculated with a universal function based on the desired parameters

- start & end scroll position
- start & end value

(even though `y` is in scope it also needs to be a parameter so the value is recalculated every time `y` changes)

Since this first intro image section adapts to the viewport height, the window `innerHeight` binding can be used to calculate the scroll positions when the transformations should happen accordingly

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0c87c32b6f5b415ba30e17a25acc654c?version=4.0.0)

```
<script>
    let y = 0
    let innerHeight

    function calculate(y, startY, endY, startValue, endValue) {
        const diffY = endY - startY
        const diffValue = endValue - startValue
        if(y < startY) {
            return startValue
        }else if(startY <= y && y <= endY) {
            const progress = (y - startY)/diffY
            return startValue + (diffValue * progress)
        }else if(endY < y){
            return endValue
        }
    }
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} bind:innerHeight={innerHeight}/>

<div id="y-scroll">innerHeight {innerHeight} - y {y}</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="home">
        <div id="img-container"
            style:transform="scale({calculate(y, 0, 1*innerHeight, 1, 1.5)})"
            style:opacity="{calculate(y, 0.7*innerHeight, 1.8*innerHeight, 1, 0)}"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>
        Following content
    </h1>
</div>

<style>
    #y-scroll {
        position: fixed;
        top: 1rem;
        left: 1rem;
        color: white;
        z-index: 10;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #content {
        height: 500vh;
    }
    #home {
        height: 260vh;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #90aaa3;
    }
    #img-container {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/19/waves.JPG?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1471&q=80");
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;       
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    :global(body) {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }
    :global(*){
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
```